# How to repackage mov/mp4 file into HLS playlist with multiple audio streams

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

I'm trying to convert some videos (in the different formats, e.g., mp4, mov) which contain **one video stream** and **multiple audio streams** into one HLS playlist with multiple audio streams (treated as languages) and only **one** video stream.

I already browsed a lot of stack threads and tried many different approaches, but I was only able to find answers for creating different HLS playlists with different audios.

Sample scenario which I have to handle:

1. I have one mov file, containing one video stream and 2 audio streams.
2. I need to create an HLS playlist from this mov file, which will use this one video stream, but would encode these 2 audio streams as language tracks (so let's say it's ENG and FRA)
3. Such prepared HLS can be later streamed in the player, and the end user would have a possibility to switch between audio tracks while watching the clip.

What I was able to achieve is to create multiple hls playlists each with different audio track.

```
ffmpeg -i "file_name.mp4" \
-map 0:v -map 0:a -c:v copy -c:a copy -start_number 0 \
-f hls \
-hls_time 10 \
-hls_playlist_type vod \
-hls_list_size 0 \
-master_pl_name master_playlist_name.m3u8 \
-var_stream_map "v:0,agroup:groupname a:0,agroup:groupname,language:ENG a:1,agroup:groupname" file_name_%v_.m3u8
```

My biggest issue is that I'm having hard time understanding how `-map` and `-var_stream_map` options should be used in my case, or if they even should be used in this scenario.

An example of the result of `ffmpeg -i` command on the original mov file which should be converted into HLS.

```
  Stream #0:0[0x1](eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080, 8786 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Apple Video Media Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      timecode        : 00:00:56:05
  Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:2[0x3](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
```

I also checked [this blogpost](https://ottverse.com/hls-packaging-using-ffmpeg-live-vod/) and I would like to achieve this exact  effect, but with video, not with audio.

> For example, -var_stream_map "v:0,a:0 v:1,a:0 v:2,a:0" implies that
> the audio stream denoted by a:0 is used in all three video renditions.

Comment: I suspect you need to first extract separately your audio/video tracks, then use 3 files (1 video + 2 audios) as input for the HLS output... This means: From the original video, get the video track (extract new file as raw `.h264` or as contained inside `.mp4` it doesn't matter, since you just want silent a video)... Then secondly from original, you extract the two audio tracks (ENG and FRA) as `.m4a`.

Answer (score 0):

The stream_map looks fine. However the hls_muxer will not create a valid HLS playlist since it is missing the codec and bitrate information from the input stream since the audio and the video stream are copied (remember `-c:v copy -c:a copy`) and not parsed / re-encoded. To add those, use the `-tag` and `-b` options to specify the properties for all your video and audio streams in HLS.

Example for your video stream:
`-tag:v:0 h264 -b:v:0 8786k`